# Testing NuxtJS Components that use Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I want to unit test components with jest in a NuxtJS Project that are using Vuetify. When I want to select a button (v-btn), jest outputs the following:

```
 [vue-test-utils]: find did not return .v-btn, cannot call text() on empty Wrapper
```

I followed the official docs of vuetify for unit testing.

```
// myComponent.vue

<template>
  <v-menu offset-y>
    <v-btn color="primary">
      myLabel
    </v-btn>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

```
// myComponent.spec.js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import MyComponent from '~/components/MyComponent'

describe('Index Switch', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  let wrapper
  let vuetify

  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify()
    wrapper = mount(MyComponent, { localVue, vuetify })
  })

  it('should have index switch button', () => {
    const myButton = wrapper.find('.v-btn')
    expect(myButton.text()).toBe('myLabel')
  })
})
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

I hope your problem is solved too

in test file like `home.spec.test`

```
const vuetify = new Vuetify()
Vue.use(Vuetify)
let localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(vuetify)
```

```
"nuxt": "^2.14.6"
"@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
```